# How to public access postgres deployed in docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

How do I get public access to postgres deployed in docker? i have forwarded ports, modified pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf. but only localhost can login successfully!
[docker-compose.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al7ND.png)

[postgresql.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAbN9.png)

[pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlaK2.png)

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TIV3.png)

[other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QThoR.png)

i have forwarded ports, modified pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf, then restart via `docker compose restart`
What I expect is to realize public access.

Answer (score 0):

For IP, It's seem like a public IP address.

Now you can connect via localhost.

So you need to check firewall inbound opens tcp  15432.

Then config port forwarding in your NAT.

To check this IP:port open in the Internet, you can use ping.eu